# capistrano (v3) deploys the same code on all roles

Tags: capistrano

If I understand correctly the standard git deploy implementation with capistrano v3 deploys the same repository on all roles. I have a more difficult app that has several types of servers and each type has its own code base with its own repository. My database server for example does not need to deploy any code.

How do I tackle such a problem in capistrano v3?

Should I write my own deployment tasks for each of the roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I tackle such a problem in capistrano v3?

All servers get the code, as in certain environments the code is needed to perform some actions. For example in a typical setup the `web` server needs your static assets, the `app` server needs your code to serve the app, and the `db` server needs your code to run migrations.

If that's not true in your environment and you don't want the code on the servers in some roles, you could easily send a pull request to add the `no_release` feature back from Cap2 in to Cap3.

You can of course take the `.rake` files out of the Gem, and load those in your Capfile, which is a perfectly valid way to use the tool, and modify them for your own needs.

The general approach is that if you don't need code on your DB server, for example, why is it listed in your deployment file?

Comment: The DB server was a bad example, but I have some other servers that have another role and take their code from another git repository. How would you solve that?

Comment: The feature is targeted for v3.1. See the issue tracker (as a result of this post) in the meantime, you can take the (official) branch with the pending code on.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm you can use `no_release: true` to disable a server from deploying the repository code.

I needed to do this so I could specifically run a restart task for a different server.

Be sure to give your server a role so that you can target it. There is a handy function called `release_roles()` you can use to target servers that have your repository code.

Then you can separate any tasks (like my restart) to be independent from the deploy procedure.

**For Example:**

```
server '10.10.10.10', port: 22, user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db assets}
server '10.10.10.20', port: 22, user: 'deploy', roles: %w{frontend}, no_release: true

namespace :nginx do

    desc 'Reloading PHP will clear OpCache. Remove Nginx Cache files to force regeneration.'
    task :reload do
        on roles(:frontend) do
            execute "sudo /usr/sbin/service php7.1-fpm reload"
            execute "sudo /usr/bin/find /var/run/nginx-cache -type f -delete"
        end
    end

end

after 'deploy:finished', 'nginx:reload'
after 'deploy:rollback', 'nginx:reload'

# Example of a task for release_roles() only
desc 'Update composer'
task :update do
  on release_roles(:all) do
    execute "cd #{release_path} && composer update"
  end
end
before 'deploy:publishing', 'composer:update'
```

I can think of many scenarios where this would come in handy.

FYI, this link has more useful examples:
https://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/property-filtering/